# Get data with react-native-scrollable-tabview

Tags: react-native

i'm a newbie with react-native, i'm using react-native-scrollable-tabview to do menu of food, and have array of object `[{"id:1","title": "Chicken"},"id":2, "title": "Cake"}.....]`  but i don't know how to put in, in child components i use re-use to show the details of list food. For static it working but dynamic it not ok. Please help me, i stck right now.
Does any one have example code fetch with data in, i very thank you for that

this is food component:

```
import { ScrollableTabView, ScrollableTabBar } from '@valdio/react-native-scrollable-tabview'

const Food = ({ navigation }) => {
    const onClickFood = (page) => {
        navigation.navigate(page)
    }
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        CallApi(
            'dish/list',
            "GET",
            null,
            null,
        )
          .then(res => setData(res.data.data));
      }, []);
      console.log(data);
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Food</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.content}>

                    <ScrollableTabView
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator
                        renderTabBar={() => (
                            <ScrollableTabBar/>
                        )}
                        tabBarUnderlineStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
                        tabBarTextStyle={styles.TextStyle}
                        tabBarInactiveTextColor='#11111170'
                        tabBarActiveTextColor='#111111'
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    >
                    </ScrollableTabView>

                </View>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
export default Food;
```

and this is food detail inside will take id to show detail

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    data={data}
                    renderItem={
                        ({ item }) => (
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('order_foood')}>
                                    <Item name={item.name}
                                        image={item.image}
                                        address={item.address}
                                    />
                                </TouchableOpacity> )
                    }
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Can you add your code ? We can't help you without more details

Comment: @BloodyMonkey tks you about your cmt, i have edited my post ^^